# What kind of spider is this? hoping its not poisonious

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

Found outdoors, after it was killed we found little tiny baby spiders on our ceilings throughout our house. really wanting to know if this spider is venomous or not as we have a baby of our own in the house..

Found in Bligh Park 2756, Sydney NSW Australia. 
I would say it’s around 10cm.

Comment: Hi Emily. Please review the [guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for writing a [tag:specied-identification] post. Specifically, we need your location and the size of the specimen. Ideally, if you can provide additional photos of the spider (especially of its abdomen and eyes) that could benefit getting a positive ID, too. Please [edit] your post with this additional information. Thanks. Please also consider taking our [tour] and checking out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)